# SASS Multi-level array

Tags: sass

I have an array :

```
$test : (
     key : ( key2 : "value 1", key3 : "value 2")
);
```

I want to change the value of key2 to be "value x".

I cant find anything in the documentation about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map-merge](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#merge):

```
$test: map-merge($test, (key: (key2: "value x")));
```